# Any set of $2015$ consecutive natural numbers contains a number whose sum of digits is divisible by $28$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that in any set of $2015$ consecutive natural numbers, there always exists a number whose sum of digits is divisible by $28$.

This is a question from Bangladesh.

I really find it difficult and have no idea. The form of the problem is like the problem of "proving that in $39$ consecutive natural numbers there is a number whose sum of digits is divisible by $11$", but at a much more difficult level.

The pigeonhole principle is the only thing I can think of, but I haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: I suppose this question was asked in year 2015, it is the reason why we have 2015 here. Tis property is still valid with 2014, or 2013, or few lower numbers. 2015 has been chosen for fun. But 28 is not for fun.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis i will try but if i can't solved it can you help ?

Comment: @Lourrran why can you confirm the problem is still true for 2013 or 2014. do you have a solution for it?

Comment: You can start with a more simple question (suggested by Jaap Scherpuis) : proof that for any integer $k ( k>0)$, at least one number in the range $[k \times 1000, k \times 1000+999]$ verifys the property : sum of digits is a multiple of $28$.

Comment: @Lourrran thanks i will try.jaap scherpuis's comment is lost and i'm quite confused :v

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $2015$ consecutive natural  numbers contain at least one of the intervals $[1000 m, 1000 m + 999]$.  If the sum of digits of $m$ is $s$, the sum of digits of these can be anything from $s$ to $s+27$.

Comment: Note that this exact method was already hinted $7$ hours prior in a [comment by Jaap Scherphuis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4696307/any-set-of-2015-consecutive-natural-numbers-contains-a-number-whose-sum-of-dig#comment9937598_4696307)

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks you :D